# What is the difference between getSuggestedMinimumHeight () and getMinimumHeight ()?

Tags: android, view, drawable

I have read the references but I'm still very confused with both terms. Here are what the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) states:

> protected int getSuggestedMinimumHeight ()
>
> Returns the suggested minimum height that the view should use. This
>   returns the maximum of the view's minimum height and the background's
>   minimum height (getMinimumHeight()).

and

> public int getMinimumHeight ()
>
> Returns the minimum height suggested by this Drawable. If a View uses
>   this Drawable as a background, it is suggested that the View use at
>   least this value for its height. (There will be some scenarios where
>   this will not be possible.) This value should INCLUDE any padding.

Does this mean that if the parent View object was set by the user as 100px height, `getMinimumHeight()` would return 100px?

Then, based on this snippet of code from a tutorial below, are these two methods interchangable there?

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec); 
.... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your quotes from 2 different documentation pages, `Drawable` and `View`, listing the `getMinimumHeight` from drawable but `getSuggestedMinimumHeight` from View.

`View` has both, `getMinimumHeight` and `getSuggestedMinimumHeight`, where the former will account for the `View` alone and the latter will also take the `getMinimumHeight` of the drawable into account.

`getMinimumHeight` on `Drawable` will tell you the minimum height the drawable should be, for whatever reason.

*So the answer is no*, you can not just switch those 2 methods. Although in most cases they will probably be interchangeable since most views have backgrounds without fixed bounds.

A proper way to measure would be to try...

1. provide at least `getSuggestedMinimumHeight`
2. if that is not possible provide `getMinimumHeight`, maybe cutting off the background in the process,
3. and if neither is possible, you will just give it as much room as you can, probably cutting off the contents and the background